# Setting up a daily partitioned index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to setup my index such that it is partitioned into daily sub-indices that I can adjust the individual settings of depending on the age of that index, i.e. >= 30 days old should be moved to slower hardware etc. I am aware I can do this with a lifecycle policy.

What I'm unable to join-the-dots on is how to setup the original index to be partitioned by day. When adding data/querying, do I need to specify the individual daily indicies or is there something in Elasticsearch that will do this for me? If the later, how does it work with adding/querying (assuming they are different?)...how does it determine the partitions that are relevant for the query/partition to add a document to? (I'm assuming there is a timestamp field - but I can't see from the docs how its all linked together)

I'm using the base Elasticsearch OSS v7.7.1 without any plugins installed.

Answer (score 1):

there's no such thing as sub indices or partitions in Elasticsearch. if you want to use ilm, which you should, then you are using aliases and multiple indices

you will need to upgrade from 7.7 - which is [EOL](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol) - and use the default distribution to get access to ilm as well

getting back to your conceptual questions, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/overview-index-lifecycle-management.html and the following few chapters dive into it. but to your questions;

- the major assumption of using ilm is that data being ingested is current, so on a rough level, data from today will end up in an index from today
- if you are indexing historic data then you may want to put that into "traditional" index names, eg `logs-2021.08.09` and then attach them to the ilm policy as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-with-existing-indices.html
- when querying, Elasticsearch will handle accessing all the indices it needs based on the request it receives. it does this via https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-field-caps.html

Comment: Im not in control of the version of elasticsearch. Sounds like I'll have to do this manually then. Thank you for your reply!